# Permissions issue when embedding Facebook event in externally hosted website

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I run a website which runs monthly events. We recently switched to using Facebook events so that we can take advantage of more streamlined social sharing. I created our first event which works just fine:

https://www.facebook.com/events/657779131055149/

I'd like to embed the post containing the event into my website so that users can indicate their attendance without having to visit Facebook. I'm copying this iframe embed code from the post mentioned above. I click the arrow to the right, and click Embed and get this code:

`<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fevents%2F657779131055149%2F&width=500" width="500" height="446" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

There's an option to preview the posting, which displays fine on Facebook. But when I paste that iframe into my website I get the following error:

`This Facebook post is no longer available. It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed.`

I'm being asked to create an app for this, which is fine. But I'm unsure of the permissions I need to request from users to allow them to do this.

1) It should be possible. Why else would Facebook offer the option of embedding content that can't be embedded.

2) I don't care about allowing a user to comment, or do any activity other than clicking the "Going/Interested" button.

I can't finalize the app creation process in the app settings until I choose permissions. I just don't know what permissions I need.

Note to WizKid...when I deselect any existing permissions for my app submission I get an alert which reads `Please select some items to submit for review`. So it seems I have to have SOME permissions, but I don't know what.

Cheers
Andy

Comment: You can create an app without choosing permissions. No permissions are totally fine. If you can't finish the creation flow you have to show us what you are doing

Comment: I've updated my original post with a more detailed description of what I'm doing, and what is happening.

Comment: Who said create an app? Why would an app solve it? And you don't submit apps you submit permissions. So if you don't want any permissions you don't submit it

Comment: I don’t think the embedded posts plugin is supposed to work for events. Documentation says, _“Only public posts from Facebook Pages and profiles can be embedded.”_ – but what you have here is not such a post, it is an event, and that’s something different.

Comment: @CBroe That makes sense I suppose. But if I'm not supposed to be able to embed an event, then why give me an embed option for one? :D